# GMail App showing my app's page in android

Tags: android, deep-linking

Always facing the problem which is depicted in the below image

[image]

Gmail icon and my app icon is there. But the page icon is my app's icon. When opening my app by clicking an url(app related) from Gmail and then minimize my app shows like this. Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the use of [up navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).  However, it is suggested that you *do* use up navigation.  Many people will argue that it isn't intuitive, but that's just the way Android handles this.

Comment: Its useful information. I have learned some from this. But not working for my current project task.

Comment: This problem happening when I press home button or recent apps button.

Comment: you are correct. The android default is opening our app in their app(other app). When we back press the source app resuming.